# PYspark erroring when sending RDD to Kafka Topic

Tags: python, apache-spark, apache-kafka, pyspark

HI all I'm a bit confused about this one.

my spark code generate the expected output however once I try and send the RDD back to kafka it is erroring every single time.  Im not quite sure what is wrong with my code.

```
 def sendkafka(messages):
    kafka = KafkaClient(kafkaip)
    producer = SimpleProducer(kafka, 'dev_test_upstream')
    for message in messages:
         producer.send_messages(message)
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure that your sendkafka() method is working as intended. It looks like you provided partial listing, so not sure if that part is working. I have a sample of how to send data to Kafka from Python, take a look [Python client for publishing and consuming message from Apache Kafka](http://wpcertification.blogspot.com/2014/08/python-client-for-publishing-and.html), you might want to use the producer.py instead of sendKafka() method